# Audio unit instrument + sampler

Tags: audio, core-audio, xcode-instruments

now i'm working on a project for creating audio unit instrument that provide the basic waveform and also provide the audio sampler. i have a problem with how to implement the audio unit instrument base to support the audio file browsing and also wonder about the Audio unit SDK that support this situation to making a sampler.

the sampler can combine with wave form then generate the new sound
This is not an IOS audio unit. and i have not much knowledge about this sampler structure

i have been search a lot, but their are no related knowledge and some source code that i can understand. pls help me for at least browsing the audio file from Au Instrument and slicing the audio data in a time domain. so i can use DSP to work with it.

regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest taking a look at the [FilterDemo](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/FilterDemo/Introduction/Intro.html) source code. It illustrates the most important aspects of the relationship between parameters, properties, UI, and the underlying DSP code. I have had some success with using the [FilterDemo](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/FilterDemo/Introduction/Intro.html) source code as a basis for converting raw DSP code, as well as AU plugins with only generic parameters (and therefore no UI), into fully integrated AU plugins with customized UI.

Also, pay close attention to the warnings, embedded in some of the source code, about renaming your UI elements, as there is a flat namespace to contend with.

Comment: very helpful. I also found out that there are a lot of sample project on [Apple Developers Resource](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/#section=Frameworks&topic=AudioUnit)